# Locking/fixing an image to an exact spot on a background image

Tags: css

I am trying to set images as links to an exact spot on a background image.  I need the image links to stay in the same space on the background image and be responsive.

I am using html and css, and have little knowledge of any other programming language.  I am trying to use a background image that is fixed and four images as links with absolute position values, but the image links move around when I change the browser window.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code for any help

Comment: #backgroundcircle {
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;
 position: fixed;
 margin-top: 8%;
 background-image: url('lagclear.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 60% auto;
 background-position: center 30%;
}

#lagtop {
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 30%;
 margin-top: 18%;
 
}

Comment: CSS code is listed above -  #backgroundcircle is the background image and #lagtop is the image link I want to set on top of the background image in an exact location regardless of browser width.   I appreciate any advise or tips!

Answer (score 0):

I can give you 2 ways to solve this as i used them before:

1: Use all measurements in %:

That is actually not responsive, but falls into the concept of fluid layout.. wich means it always fills the whole that it can on whatever size.

2: Use media queries:

that is considered responsive, because at each key sizing it will change your positionning:

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .element {
    /*INSERT POSITIONING STYLES HERE (POSITIONING[top, right, bottom, left])*/
  }
}

.element {
  /*INSERT DEFAULT STYLING HERE (COLORS, DISPLAY MODE, VISIBILITY, OPACITY)*/
}
```

REMEMBER: in order to position to work, you have to either set the element to position: fixed/absolute/relative.

Hope i helped out. In case of doubt, just ask me!

Comment: Thanks so much for the assistance.  I will give it a try!